# 403 Not Authorized Using socialtables API

Tags: social-tables

Get URL :https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/products
Header : Authorization :Bearer b465820782e1b07db9b38d6e351883517ccc0dcf

Response
{
    "code": "NotAuthorized",
    "message": "Not Authorized"
}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: using some APIs getting "Not Authorized" error in socialtables API

Comment: If you give more details we can help you. It appears you have an invalid token or are passing it incorrectly. What are you trying to do? Who is calling socialtables API? Are you following a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an oauth token to authenticate.

See https://developer.socialtables.com/docs/authentication/ for how to get a token and authenticate.